# how to run php as background process

Tags: php, background-process, pclose

I have a problem when executing the PHP files as background process.
I have two PHP file as follow :

**index.php**

```
<?php   
    $cmd = "php cmdReadReport.php";
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    } 
    else { 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
?>
```

**cmdReadExcel.php**

```
<?php
    $reportname = "./report/lw321.xls";
    $thereport = new Report();
    $thereport->readReport($reportname)
?>
```

My goal is to run Report.readReport as background process. readReport function is function which reads Excel file and saves its rows to database.

I have followed the tutorial but there is no result/no rows inserted. Is there anything wrong in the code?

Regards,

Comment: What happen if you run it in "foreground"?

Comment: @Passerby there might be some reasons, like "file is too large", or script timeout, because there is a lot of rows in there.

Comment: @CORRUPT I only meant to see if `cmdReadExcel.php` actually functions properly. I myself use background technique to do things too, and OP's handling seems fine at a first glance.

Comment: It will take long time (data is big). I have tried run it in "foreground" with smaller data and it worked fine.

Comment: i have tested to run the command in Windows command prompt too and it worked fine

Comment: @passerby is there any security setting?

Comment: @user2020692 Yes, what priviledge your server/PHP have? There might be chance that THAT user don't have enough permission on `cmd.exe`. In an XP + IIS + normal user account machine, I had to copy `cmd.exe` to PHP installation directory for this technique to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could initiate script execution from client instead of server. Like this:

```
www.example.com/scripts/cmdReadReport.php?keypass=Giw3m4d9BaJO0ua0WFtG
```

Then just request this page with CURL or something. This approach is more portable.